# Can a person increase in joy before Adar?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It is written:

> משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה (When Adar comes we increase in joy)

If a person started to get happy on Tu b'Shevat instead, is this permissible b'dieved (after the fact)?  What if someone had an intention beforehand to increase joy before Adar and carried it out, for example, they told Purim Torah (offline) in Shevat?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Off the cuff, I believe that you can start being happy the Wednesday before Adar starts. I will have to investigate this.

Answer (score 3):

Not only is it permitted, but it is a mitzva to be happy, to drink, and even to do the four mitzvos of Purim before Adar starts as the Haggada tells us.

> יכול מראש חדש תלמוד לומר לקיים את ימי הפורים האלה בזמניהם
>   יכול רק בו ביום בלבד תלמוד לומר בכל שנה שכל השנה כולה כשר להוללות ושכרות שנאמר לדעת הוללות ושכרות

Answer (score 2):

It was an issue disputed by Beis Hillel and Beis Shammai.

They agreed that the simcha increase happens 2 weeks after the new year for trees, as on that day you gather the fruits to start making the wine and liquor.

However they dispute as to which date the new year for trees is. See the first mishnah for Rosh Hashanah.

Beis Shammai hold it is the first of Shvat, so they also follow that you increase the simcha from Tu Bishvat.

So if you did it from this date you would be following the practice of Beis Shammai.

The reason for the celebration 2 weeks after is of course the G'zeira Shava with 15th / 15th. Sukkot is the celebration on the 15th day i.e. 2 weeks after Rosh Hashanah. Pesach is the one on the 15th day from the 1st Nisan new year. So there is also one for the new year for trees..

Answer (score 2):

Actually one is happier on Tisha B'Av than on Purim. One starts increasing his Simcha on Rosh Chodesh Adar and continues increasing it until Rosh Chodesh Av when he starts decreasing it. Thus on Tisha B'Av he is at a higher level of Simcha than on Purim as on Purim he just started increasing his Simcha and on Tisha B'Av he just started decreasing his Simcha. Thus if one starts early he will be too B'Simcha on Purim and it is therefore prohibited.

(Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim volume 5)

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55554/4794

Answer (score 1):

Their is another statement ([Taanit 4:6](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Taanit.4.6)) that teaches

> משנכנס אב, ממעטין בשמחה

Now, it's not only in Av that we reduce our joy, because we also reduce our joy for Sefirah.

The Gemara on that Mishnah ([29a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=29&format=pdf), bottom of the page) draws a comparison between *mishenichnas Av* and *mishenichnas Adar*:

> **כשם** שמשנכנס אב ממעטין בשמחה **כך** משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה

So we can learn from this comparison that just as limited joy isn't limited to Av, increased joy isn't limited to Adar.