# PTIJ: It's not Rosh Chodesh Adar for me yet. Do I need to filter PTIJ posts?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I live in the USA where it is not yet Rosh Chodesh Adar. However there are Israelis for whom it is Rosh Chodesh Adar, and they are posting Purim Torah questions to Mi Yodeya. Am I halachically obligated to filter out PTIJ posts until it is Rosh Chodesh Adar for me as well?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This seems more like a meta question to me, no?

Comment: the new month is determined by where YOU happen to be, as defined by your local vaad hakashrut -- as they say, Chiddush b'makom teuda.

Comment: @Daniel If it asked if site policy demanded he not look, that would be meta. He's asking a halachic question. A very important one, in fact! :)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55196/3483

Comment: Check out the International Date Line threads.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The halacha as not brought in Shulchan Aruch is משנכנס אדר מרבים בשמחה, when Adar enters you increase happiness.

So as long as you grumble and complain about the fact that it isn't really Adar yet, and get no happiness out of the whole thing, you could look at these questions.

If you can ruin the fun for others, הרי זה משובח.

Comment: Ouch! I sense a lot of sarcasm embedded in that humor :-&

Comment: This is the best answer ever given on MY.

Answer (score 8):

On the first day of Adar, the court used to start announcing the collection of shekalim ([Shekalim 1:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h24.htm)), because they couldn't use the new shekalim until a month later. "Shekel" means "weight." So if you can't weight, you're following an ancient tradition. So not filtering is obviously the weigh to go.

Comment: What if I was a Jewish doctor? Because then I'd have lots of patients.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that due to the concept of דאקדומי פורימתורה לא מקדמינן (which is the Girsa of some Acharonim on Megillah 5a), one would be Chayav to filter it.  However, the Ritva ([Megillah 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Megillah.5a.9?lang=he&with=Megillah&lang2=he)) says:

> ובתענית שלפני פורי' שנהגו להקדימו ליה משום דההוא תענית תשובה היא ולית בה משום אקדומי פורימתורה כלל ולא עוד אלא שתענית יחיד היא

For the Taanis Shelifnei Purim (answering before Purim, i.e. Mi Yodeya Purim Torah), which the custom is to make earlier, it is because the point of such an answering is to give the correct Teshuva (answer), and therefore the above concept of Akdumei (above) does not apply.  Also, it is because it is only the answering of one person.

Therefore, according to the Ritva, there are a few points that must be noted:

- You do not need to filter the PTIJ posts, as "Akdumei" does not apply
- You may only do this so you can answer the PTIJ questions, which is the whole point of them being asked.
- However, due to the fact that it is a Taanis Yachid, you may not participate in any Community Wiki answers

Answer (score 1):

What's confusing, here, is not as much M.Y.'s policy, but what standards they are using to define Rosh Hodesh Adar.

As you know, originally, witnesses were used to declare the molad, and then, Sanhedrin declared Rosh Hodesh after confirming things. So, I think we need to ask the moderators, here, if they think they are like Sanhedrin, and if they really declared Rosh Hodesh, or not. Who were the witnesses that showed up, or are we not allowed to know?

I'm not concerned about how long it takes to send the messengers, as posting the declaration on the web, would, nowadays, quickly get the message out.